# ListView + ObjectDataSource SelectMethod called twice when EnableViewState="false"

Tags: asp.net, listview, objectdatasource

**Note:** This question has been completely modified now that I have a simpler example.

I have set up a sample page which only has a `ListView` and `ObjectDataSource`.  The first time the page comes up (`!IsPostBack`), my `GetList` method is called once.  After paging (`IsPostBack`), the `GetList` method is called twice--the first time with the old paging values and the second time with the new values.

If I set `EnableViewState="true"` on the `ListView`, then the `GetList` method is only called once.  It seems to me that the `ListView` wants an "initial state", which it either gets from `ViewState` or by re-running the method.

Is there any way to disable ViewState on the `ListView` and also prevent `SelectMethod` from being called twice?

ASPX page:

```
    <asp:ListView ID="TestListView" runat="server" DataSourceID="ODS" EnableViewState="false">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />

            <asp:DataPager ID="TestPager" runat="server" PageSize="10">
                <Fields>
                    <asp:NumericPagerField />
                </Fields>
            </asp:DataPager>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div><%# Eval("Title") %></div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>

    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ODS" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetList" SelectCountMethod="GetListCount"
        TypeName="Website.Test" EnablePaging="true" />
```

ASPX code-behind:

```
namespace Website
{
    public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public IList<DataItem> GetList(int maximumRows, int startRowIndex)
        {
            return GetListEnumerable().Skip(startRowIndex).Take(maximumRows).ToList();
        }

        public IEnumerable<DataItem> GetListEnumerable()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                yield return new DataItem { Title = i.ToString() };
            }
        }

        public int GetListCount()
        {
            return 100;
        }
    }

    public class DataItem
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Either turn ODS caching on.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ODS" ... EnableCaching="true" />
```

This way the GetList will be called only when new data is needed. Post backs to pages that already had data retrieved will use the cached version and not call the GetList.

Or move your DataPager out of the ListView and set the PagedControlID property.

Comment: I thought of caching, but in my case there are infinite parameter possibilities, so I would want the cache duration to be very small (say, 10 seconds tops).  If the user pages after the 10 seconds, it would still double query, which slows down the page quite a bit.  Enabling ViewState would be a better option here.  Moving the DataPager out of the ListView didn't help--it still double queried.  I'm wondering if I can directly or indirectly (through Reflection) set `BaseDataBoundControl.RequiresDataBinding`.

Comment: I tried setting `RequiresDataBinding` to false through Reflection and that prevents the double query.  However, it's only the first query (before the paging) that occurs, so I can't use it.  I guess I'll leave ViewState on for now.

Comment: I didn't think about parameters. I've no idea how caching is implemented when it comes to that. However, moving pager out of the listview did the trick for me. I guess it is not a reliable solution then. The RequiresDataBinding gets overriden in several places. If time permits, you could try to create your own control from ListView and handle both CreateChildren and RequiresDataBinding. Then, there is always that ViewState... :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should be using the OnSelecting event.

What happens is that ObjectDataSource calls the method SelectMethod **twice**

1. First time it gets the data.
2. Next time it gets the count.

So I think you have to implement the OnSelecting event

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ODS" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetList" SelectCountMethod="GetListCount" 
    OnSelecting="ods_Selecting">
    TypeName="Website.Test" EnablePaging="true" />
```

and then cancel the event when the ObjectDataSource tries to call the count method.

```
 protected void ods_Selecting(object sender,
                ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
 {
      if (e.ExecutingSelectCount)
      {
           //Cancel the event   
           return;
      }
}
```

You can look for full implementation as mentioned in the link below
http://www.unboxedsolutions.com/sean/archive/2005/12/28/818.aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: It shouldn't call select to get count when SelectCountMethod is provided. In the case above, it is called twice on postback and on prerender each time while creating child controls.

Comment: @Ruslan: If you debug you can see that ods_Selecting event will be hit twice.

Comment: There's some confusion here.  My `SelectMethod` caches the count which the `SelectCountMethod` uses, therefore the DB isn't hit twice for that reason.  There is the `SelectMethod`, `SelectCountMethod` and the `OnSelecting` event.  Normally (with **ViewState enabled**), the `SelectMethod` and `SelectCount` methods get called **once**.  The `OnSelecting` gets called **twice**, once with `e.ExecutingSelectCount = false`, then with `e.ExecutingSelectCount = true`.  With **ViewState disabled**, `SelectMethod` and `SelectCountMethod` are called **twice**.  `OnSelecting` gets called **four times**.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where it worked different depending on browser. IE one way and all other browsers one way..  Might not be the same issue as you have.

I solved it this way:

```
        protected void DropDownDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Issue with IE - Disable ViewState for IE browsers otherwhise the dropdown will render empty.
        DropDownList DDL = (DropDownList)sender;
        if (Request.Browser.Browser.Equals("IE", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            DDL.ViewStateMode = System.Web.UI.ViewStateMode.Disabled;
        else
            DDL.ViewStateMode = System.Web.UI.ViewStateMode.Inherit;           
    }
```

Comment: Mine alway renders (it's never empty) and the browsers don't make a difference in this case.